# text-center class will not be applied

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a span tag with some text inside.

```
<span class="text-primary text-center"> You can try your own values in the following form: </span>
```

The problem is that only text-primary class will be applied.Any ideas?
I have no css overiding those classes

Comment: use firebug and see which styles are applied to your span tag. Also a span with center text is not visible, if you replace the span with a p tag you will see its working

Comment: @VDesign why isn't a span with that class visible?

Comment: view my answer which will show you the problem

Comment: I have no css only bootstrap css

Comment: then I think VDesign has your answer, you won't be able to center align text in an inline element as it will be the width of your text

Comment: just set the span to `display:block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text-align applies ONLY to block elements not to inline elements so if you want to use a span with text-align center you have to change its display:

```
span{
display:block;
}
```

or use a block element(p for example)
For more information have a look here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-align-property

Comment: It's dangerous to apply `display:block;` to all the spans, it will most likely break whatever design is in place. Target that span specifically or use a `block` element like `<p>` or `<div>`.

Answer (score 2):

See my fiddle which will show you the problem using span:

http://jsfiddle.net/VDesign/zs03d7kh/

**HTML**

```
<span class="text-primary text-center">Test</span>
<p class="text-primary text-center">Test</p>
```

**CSS**

```
span {
    background: #ff0000;
}

p {
    background: #00ff00;
}
```

**Explanation:**

De display property of a span is default `inline`, if you change it to `block` then it will work.

Comment: Apart from the text not being centered i can't see something else

Answer (score 1):

`text-center` won't do anything on an inline element like `<span>`. If you want text to be centered, put it in a block element like `<p>`.

Example:

```html
<span style="text-align:center;">Inline centered text</span>
<p style="text-align:center;">Block centered text</p>
```

Comment: what is the difference your answer has with the one I gave?

Comment: I explained the problem? Seriously I don't even remember seeing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is causing your issue. You need to over-ride it like the following

```
.text-primary.text-center { text-align:center }
```

This allows the `.text-center` properties to be applied as well. Notice there is no space between the two classes in the definition, that essentially means AND instead of a child element.

Another note a `span` is not a block level element. You probably need to add `display:inline-block` to your definition

Comment: if you apply .text-center it is directly visible, try it in a jsfiddle

Comment: I am working on a project that is not allowed to override or add new css files

Comment: it depends on the specificity of the original CSS, no way of knowing without seeing the CSS